# obtaining a unique set with javas xpath

Tags: java, xpath

Given the following xml document (assuming more books then actually listed) and using the java implementation of xpath.
What expression would I use to find a unique set of author names?

```
<inventory>
    <book year="2000">
        <title>Snow Crash</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <isbn>0553380958</isbn>
        <price>14.95</price>
    </book>

    <book year="2005">
        <title>Burning Tower</title>
        <author>Larry Niven</author>
        <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
        <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
        <isbn>0743416910</isbn>
        <price>5.99</price>
    </book>

    <book year="1995">
        <title>Zodiac</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <isbn>0553573862</isbn>
        <price>7.50</price>
    </book>

    <!-- more books... -->

</inventory>
```

Comment: Can xpaths do that? I'd just pull out the authors and put them in a ... (wait for it) ... Set.

Comment: @CPerkins, you and I had the same idea :)

Comment: I am looking at ways to extract the necessary data from pre-existing web services. In this case I'm looking at extracting unique sets of data to facilitate filtering functions.

If it was a case where I could get all the necessary data pre-formatted exactly the way I wanted it all the time. I guess I could do away with xpath in it's entirety. But in this case I'm not going to be able to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Set<String> uniqueAuthors = new HashSet<String>();
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//book/author/text()");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) {
    uniqueAuthors.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
}
```

I used the excellent article "[The Java XPath API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html)" as a reference.

XPath Version 1.0 cannot, in general, select distinct values, so I inserted the authors into a `Set`. At the end of the `for` loop, the set will contain all of the authors.

Comment: +1 But I wonder why the sample data in the OP is exactly the same as in the linked article.

Comment: That would be because I took the sample data from the same article. The solution given here (which isn't in the article) is a good solution but not quite what I was looking for, I was hoping to determine if there was an xpath query itself which returns a unique set, not whether I could extract a unique set from a query.

Comment: @J E Bailey: XPath does not have a way to select a set of unique values. However, XQuery does: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_distinct-values.html

Comment: @Daniel Trebbian: So, in following up with the xquery lead it appears that the distinct-values function is a part of xpath 2.0 specification.

There's a nice summary of the differences here -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188789.aspx.

Where it also depicts a xpath 1.0 unique select function with which the dictinct-values was supposed to be replace. In the case of the sample xml I had it would be //author[not(preceding::author = .)] which answers my question :)

Comment: @J E Bailey: Interesting. I wasn't aware of the new `distinct-values` function in XPath 2.0, but note that the Java XPath API is still XPath Version 1.0, so you may not be able to use it yet. Also, I saw tricks that used `preceding-sibling::` as a way of selecting distinct values, but it seems to me that to use this trick in this case, all authors would need to appear in the document *alphabetically*. Therefore, I don't know if the `preceding-sibling::` location path trick is truly equivalent.

Comment: @Daniel Trebbian: As a follow up for completeness. I checked up on the preceding-sibling:: function, I wouldn't classify it as a trick, what it is effectively doing is looking at the set of all prior nodes and checking all the nodes to see if there is a match against the current node. So being in alphabetical order isn't an issue. However, from the reading I've done, and based on how the implementation is done, the length of time to process the list would grow exponentially with the list size. So in the end you're solution  is probably the most effective.